# How to Inheried Interface methods through to the subclasses in C#

Tags: c#

I have:

I:

```
public interface I
{
    void Something();
}
```

A:

```
public class A : I
{
    public void Something()
    {
    }
}
```

B:

```
public class B : A
{
}
```

Why isn't B forced to implement (the decired) Something method, as expected?

Do I really have to inheried I on all my B's(subclasses to A)?

```
public class B : A, I
{
    public void Something()
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you want all classes to implement method `Something` when inheriting `A`, you might consider making `A` an abstract class and `Something` its abstract method.

Comment: Yes that was the trick I was looking for. I also learned that I needed to add the keyword override to the method in the subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B isn't forced to implement I, because it's already implemented in A.

If you want to force B to implement it, you have to make it abstract in A, or not implement the interface on A, only implement I in B.

On a different note, if you want to allow B to override the method defined in A, you should make the method virtual in A, and then use the override keyword to override the method in B.  Right now your Something method is not virtual in A, so if you try to override it in B, the compiler will either give you and error or a warning stating that you are "hiding" the method Something in a base class.

Comment: by using the "new" keyword you can tell the compiler that hiding is the intended behavior and not get the warning.

Comment: Yep, I'm aware of that, but it seemed like just one more thing to try to talk about.

Comment: Ah, i forgot to use the abstract keyword on my superclasses (B is actually a superclass of C), so I get the decired have-to-implement function thing in Class C. Thanks! 
@ other people, thanks also, u all teached me something!
My solution is a mix of using: abstract and override.

Answer (score 5):

Because `B` **already has** a `Something` method which inherited from `A`.

So `B` is not **forced** to implement `Something` method. **B** on the other hand, it's free to override `A`'s `Something` method if it needs to, provided `Something` method was marked as `virtual` in class `A`:

```
public class B : A
{
    public override void Something()
    {
        // B's something
    } 
}
```

Comment: Note that this will fail because A's `Something` is not virtual.

Comment: Yes. Just realized and fixed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why would you expect it to? Since B is already deriving from A, it has the method implemented in A. Therefore it need not implement the method again in B

Think of B as an union of A and B classes. So B essentially has all the methods implemented in A. Also A cannot reduce the scope of method from `public` to `private`, so there is no way B cannot have access to `something` function.